# Pass String in Postgres Query

Tags: postgresql, psql, crosstab

I am using Postgresql 9.3 and what I am trying to do is Passing column names as string into my query. For newtable my column number can be dynamic sometimes it might be 3 or more for which I am trying to select column from another table and pssing relut of my query as string in the existing query
Please help how can i do this

```
select * from crosstab (
    'select "TIMESTAMP_S","VARIABLE","VALUE" from archieve_export_db_a3 group by 1,2,3 order by 1,2',
    'select distinct "VARIABLE" From archieve_export_db_variables order by 1'
) AS newtable (TIMESTAMP_S int,_col1 integer,_col2 integer);
```

Comment: you must generate that whole query dynamically http://www.joshslauson.com/2014/11/15/automatically-define-postgresql-crosstab-output-columns/

Comment: can you demonstrate how can i generate it dynamically